# Migrating from `form_for` over to the new `form_with`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-for

How would one go about converting from `form_for` over to `form_with` for the following:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

I've looked through Rails' `form_with` documentation but haven't found any relevant examples.

Thanks!

Comment: You can find lot of examples here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements

Comment: **Before form_with was introduced in Rails 5.1 its functionality used to be split between form_tag and form_for. Both are now soft-deprecated.** Whatever code is working with `form_for` should still work with `form_with`

Comment: I'm aware of that @Thang, however their syntax is a bit different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`form_with` has the `scope:` option that changes input name prefixes, ids and the for attribute of labels. As far as I can tell it does the exact same thing as the `as:` option for `form_for`.

> `:scope` - The scope to prefix input field names with and thereby how
>   the submitted parameters are grouped in controllers.
>
> ```
> # Adding a scope prefixes the input field names:
> <%= form_with scope: :post, url: posts_path do |form| %>
>   <%= form.text_field :title %>
> <% end %>
> # =>
> <form action="/posts" method="post" data-remote="true">
>   <input type="text" name="post[title]">
> </form>
> ```
>
> https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

So the equivalent call is:

```
<%= form_with(
      model: resource, 
      scope: resource_name, 
      url: password_path(resource_name), 
      method: :post
    ) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```rb
= form_with model: resource, scope: resource_name,
            url: password_path(resource_name), method: :post do |f|
```

also `form_with` does not generate classes and ids for elements, if you need these - add them manually

Documentation [in api](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) is much more detailed than in guides at the moment.

Comment: You're missing the `as: resource_name` option. I'm guessing this is from Devise and it uses it to make the form keys generic instead of getting the keys off the model.

Comment: Thanks for your input Vasted! @max indeed, that's exactly the part I can't find any examples for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the `as: resource_name` and `html: { method: :post }` in this case. Simply use the `model: resource` in `form_with` and you are good to go.

As per the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with):

> `model` infers both the URL and scope.
>
> So, using this
>
> ```rb
> <%= form_with model: Post.new do |form| %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to something like:
>
> ```rb
> <%= form_with scope: :post, url: posts_path do |form| %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

But since Devise uses a different helper method, `password_path` in this case, to generate certain URL. You only need to use the `url:` option along with `model:` in `form_with` like below:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: resource, url: password_path(resource_name)) do |form| %>
```

will generate something like:

```html
<form action="/users/password" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```